# Scaling AWS Lambda with SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scaling, amazon-sqs, autoscaling

I want to use SQS for calling Lambda.
An execution time of lambda function is 3 minutes.
I want to execute 1000 lambda functions at once, so I send 1000 messages to SQS queue

But according to an AWS documentation

> Amazon Simple Queue Service supports an initial burst of 5 concurrent function invocations and increases concurrency by 60 concurrent invocations per minute.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html

So I should wait a few minutes until all messages will be processed. Is there any workaround to call 1000 concurrent lambda and avoid "cold start"?

UPD: I got answer from AWS support

> You are correct that SQS will start at an initial burst of 5 and
>   increase by a concurrency of 60 per minute. Scaling rates can't be
>   increased

Answer (score 0):

If you see the **Automatic Scaling** section of the documentation page that describes the autoscaling behaviour under sudden load. I don't think cold start would be a problem. The first batch of concurrent Lambdas executions would likely see the cold start and all the subsequent invocations would be fine.